# CleanURL issues even after disabling it

Tags: users, media, .htaccess, uri

So I recently transferred my site to a new server and disabled cleanURLs because of facing many errors. But due to this, I'm facing multiple issues:

1. Sometimes (not all the time)- when I save a form in the admin (editing user profiles/nodes/content etc.), the page redirects to a cleanurl (even though it's disabled) - for example www.example.com/admin/people instaed of www.example.com/?q=admin/people - I have no idea why this randomly keeps happening
2. When I upload user pictures for users and set Image style as thumbnail, the original image gets uploaded properly, but the thumbnail never gets generated adding to the fact that the image path generated for the user is absurdly as follows: www.example.com/?q=sites/default/files/styles/thumbnail/public/pictures/example.jpg - Is this because of cleanURLs again?
3. Moreover, I can't even re-enable cleanURLs since it gives me a negative test result.

I tried replacing the .htaccess file and it didn't solve the issue. Maybe it's my server configuration?

Even yet, I don't want cleanURLs enabled at all. So how do I fully disable it? Or is disabled anyway and this is some other issue?

Please help! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can force clean urls to be `Off` with the following line in your `settings.php` file. Add the following to the end -- this settings overrides even whatever is in your database; be sure to remove it later.

```
/* Turn off clean urls */
$conf['clean_url'] = 0;
```

Whether or not your webserver supports Clean Urls depends on its' configuration. I recommend reviewing the [Getting Started with Clean URLs Guide](https://drupal.org/getting-started/clean-urls).

Answer (score 0):

it's not solved issues with drupal core

after panic search i use this module

https://www.drupal.org/project/imageinfo_cache